# Whitch is faster? PHP explode or mysql join two tables on 2 ids where condition?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

Let's say:

1. first case scenario: one table

   products(product_id, title, description, ..., images);

but in field images we have images separated by '; '

Ex:
/23/25/3/flower1.jpg; /23/25/3/flower5.jpg; /23/25/3/flower7.jpg

if I make a simple mysql query,and then use php to explode, then I will have all images in one array and then to echo all images,

```
$images=explode('; ',$row['images']);
```

2. second case 3tables necessary

   products(product_id, title, descr, ...,);

   images(image_id, imageurl);

   products_images(products_images_id, product_id, image_id);

So, to get images for a specified product I need to do a mysql query with a join.

Can you prove witch case is faster to echo link images?

Comment: *"Can you prove wich case is faster"*: you prove this by measuring the execution times. I think you can do this yourself.

Comment: first case is faster, but people use to say that is not, or that this is not the way to build tables, or is not what tables should be

Comment: If you don't think you need a structured relational database design and performance is so critical, there isn't much point in using a relational database server in the first place. There're other storage engines aimed at speed rather than features. However, you may want to think what will happen when you need to query or update information in a non-trivial way.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to fetch the whole list of images, and never want to use SQL to do anything else with that list, then storing them in a semicolon-separated list is fine.

There are legitimate uses for denormalization. But be aware that you are optimizing for one task by making other tasks harder.

Think about how you would do tasks such as the following if the images are stored in a semicolon-separated list:

- Search for a specific image
- Add a new image to the list
- Delete an image from the list
- Fetch the list in sorted order
- Count how many images in the list for a given product
- Support a longer list of images than fits in one string column
- Search for products that share a given image
- Many other things you might think of doing

Then you should use the normalized table design and store one image per row.